# PHP pack function alternative for Node.js

Tags: php, node.js, pack

I'm trying to connect to PayBox payment service. They propose a PHP solution, but I'm using Nodejs. In their solution they use PHP pack function of which I can't find an equivalent in Node.js.

This is the target:

```
$binKey = pack("H*", $secretKeyTest);
```

I found a package *Hipack* but it has couple of issues.

Comment: So did my answer help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to convert a hexadecimal string into a binary buffer, then something like this may work for you:

```
var binKey =  Buffer.from(secretKeyTest, "hex");
```

For more info on how to use buffers in Node, see:

- https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

Comment: Yes it did Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I have the code new Buffer(salt, "base64") and I want to convert it into PHP. Do you have any solution? please help me.

Comment: Hi @ManishJangir, bit late
try this function **base64_encode(string $string): string**